# Generic class to distinguish whether to use a 32 bit or a 64 bit C#

Tags: c#, generics, 32bit-64bit

I have an application that needs to check whether to use a 32 bit or a 64 bit driver dll. return value is the driver of 32/64 bit dll. Think I need to do a generic class. Someone got an idea to do that ?

```
public Driver_64/Driver_32 Connect()
{
   if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
   {
      Driver64bit.driver drv = new Driver64bit.driver(ip,parm)
      return drv;
   }
   else
   {
         Driver32bit.driver drv = new Driver32bit.driver(ip,parm)
         return drv;
   }
}
```

Comment: Generics? What about inheritance or interfaces?

Comment: Make a generic class/method with <T> where T : IDriver and IDriver has .GetDriverInstance()

Comment: @Traubenfuchs may be better to `GetDriverInstance`?

Comment: That makes more sense, yes (;

Comment: As a side note, you *probably* need to check `Is64BitProcess`, but it may depend on what **exactly** you are doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, hide this implementation detail behind an interface:

```
public interface IDriver {
    void DoSomething(...);
    //...
}
```

If you control the types, then have `Driver64bit.driver` and `Driver32bit.driver` implement the interface; otherwise, add classes to encapsulate this:

```
internal sealed class Driver32 : IDriver {
    private readonly Driver32bit.driver driver;
    public Driver32(Driver32bit.driver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
    void IDriver.DoSomething(...) {
        driver.DoSomething(...);
    }
}
```

(and a `Driver64`, obviously)

now just return `IDriver`:

```
public IDriver Connect() {
   // ...
}
```

either returning `drv` or `new Driver32(drv)` / `new Driver64(drv)`, depending on whether you could make the types implement the interface versus adding a wrapper type.

You can also use base-classes, but interfaces are generally more flexible.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense for the IDriver to offer an architecture neutral method GetDriverInstance() that's supposed to give back the appropriate version and Get64bitDriverInstance()/Get32bitDriverInstance for explicit access?

Comment: @Traubenfuchs why? what useful purpose would that address?

Comment: He could get an architecture appropriate driver-object with a single line.

Comment: @Traubenfuchs again, what useful purpose would that address? the entire point of encapsulation and abstraction is that the caller **doesn't need to worry about that** - they just work with the abstraction, and let the implementation worry about those details internally.

Comment: No it is first when I ask the dll which can either be a driver_32 bit or a driver_64 that I know which driver to use. Is it enough to use Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem to find out the bit version of dll ? Is it possible to make a generic class or do I have to make two classes for 32 bit and 64 bit where I practice the driver instructions ?